# Jekyll theme works local but not GitHub page

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages

Jekyll theme doesn't show on GitHub pages, but it does work local

[how it works on local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpYtn.png)

The theme that I am trying to use is: `poole/lanyon`

here are things I have tried

- erasing baseurl (on `_config.yml`)
- setting baseurl to "" (as it is now)
- setting baseurl and url the same

the page is: https://korgunnlind.github.io
Please help!
Thnx guys:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's requesting stylesheets from HTTP and not HTTPS.

Change `http://korgunnlind.github.io//public/css/poole.css` to `https://korgunnlind.github.io/public/css/poole.css`.

Comment: Thnx for pitching in! Works just fine:)